# Python PIL cant put a image on a tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Im trying to put a image in a tkinter window with this code...

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk

my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Imagem1.png"))
MyLabel = Label(root, image=my_img)
MyLabel.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

But it keeps getting this error "name 'PhotoImage' is not defined"

Comment: Umm, prolly because you missed the parenthesis with `Tk`: `root = Tk()`. But however, that would never bring a `NameError`.

Comment: its still crashed and im watching a tutorial for the guy the code work just fine

Comment: Then link the video, and make sure to copy paste exactly the same code you are using. Also make sure you save the file before running it. So far, this code works fine.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXPyB4XeYLA&t=5146s 1:26:53

Comment: The code in the video seems fine. Your code also seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have a error at `root=Tk` -> `root=Tk()`

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()

my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Image1.png"))
MyLabel = Label(root, image=my_img)
MyLabel.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: I have put Image1.png as image path if your image name is imagem1.png go with that

Comment: But `root = Tk` will not give a `SyntaxError`..?

Comment: you missed the parenthesis with  root = Tk()

Comment: Except that, The code looks fine and working properly on python 3.x, if its stills showing error my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(" provide path of image here"))

Comment: e.g. C:/hxn/desktop/image.png